# Visual Studio IntelliCode not predicting methods and variables

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense, pywin32, intellicode

I'm using python and VS and when I'm using classes that are downloaded through pip IntelliCode doesn't provide an auto copletion of methods and variables from those modules.
As you can see there is two problems:
1. For some reason VS highlited `excel` variable in blue color
2. When I try to look through all possible variables VS tells me that there is only 1 method `mro()` but it can clearly be seen that several lines above there are `excel.Visible = False`, and I should say that this is a working code.
[IntelliCode does not offer to finish the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6NMw.jpg)

I read some advises and went to Tools->Options->Text editor->All languages->Hide advanced members (unchecked this)
Now I have some other general methods
[After options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWxzS.jpg)

It should be notised that VS can see all my packages
[VS packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iToGS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Python is supported in VSCode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/intellicode-visual-studio-code

Can you report your first issue (where you don't see completion) through Visaul Studio Feedback by clicking the feedback button in the right upper corner in Visual Studio.